# Передача файла через Socket. Не работает flush()

Tags: java, android, сокет

Добрый день.

Передаю файл с android клиента на сервер через сокет. После предачи файла вызываю **out.flush()**, далее передются строковые данные. На сервере после получения файла при попытке считать строковые данные выскакивает **EOFException**. Почему то сервере эти строковые данные записываются в конец файла.

Пробовал выключать алгоритм Нэгла: **socket.setTcpNoDelay(true)**, но результат тот же. Знающие люди, помогите кто чем может!!!!!!!!!!!!

Клиент:

```
    InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverAdress);
    Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
    socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    out.writeInt((int) file.length());

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    while (true) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[kB64];
        Integer len = fis.read(buffer);
        if(len == -1) {
             break;
        }
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        out.flush();
   }
   fis.close();

   out.writeUTF("some text");
   out.flush();
```

Сервер:

```
 Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
 socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
 DataInputStream in = DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
 int i = 0;
 byte[] buffer = new byte[kB64];
 Integer fileSize = in.readInt();
 while(i<fileSize){
    len = in.read(buffer);
    i+=len;
    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    fos.flush();
 }
 fos.close();
 //..
 // Здесь получаем EOFException
 String someString = in.readUTF();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все потому, что последний блок читает все до конца потока, включая дополнительный текст. Представьте, что у Вас файл длинной 64кб + 100 байт. Вы его отправили и еще 100 байт текста. На сервере Ваш код считает сначала 64кб, а потом сразу все оставшиеся 200 байт.

Т.е. код клиента корректный, а сервер надо переписать. Проверять, если осталось до конца файла менее, чем размер буфера, и читать только остаток.

Как-то вот так:

```
while(i < fileSize) {
  len = in.read(buffer, 0, (fileSize - i < buffer.length) ? fileSize - i : buffer.length);
  i += len;
  fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
  fos.flush();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Ответ очевиден, но почему то я искал его не там где надо))